# STM32F7 Discovery - where are the LEDs?

Tags: embedded, stm32, gpio, led, stm32f7

I am learning about ARM development on my **STM32F7** Discovery Kit (w/ STM32F746NGH6 Microcontroller) and I'm trying to write a "blinky" program without using high level libraries.

Reading the documentation, I couldn't figure out which MCU pins are all those onboard LED's connected to? What is the right document to check?

Looking at the board I can see some LEDs (LD1, LD2, ...), but **how can I reach them in program**? I don't see them in header files and if they are controlled via GPIO pins, how to I know which ones?

In the [user manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/f0/14/c1/b9/95/6d/40/4d/DM00190424.pdf/files/DM00190424.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00190424.pdf) there's no mention of any LED, except in the electrical schematics (where none of the LEDs is connected directly to the MCU afaik- they serve mostly as hard-wired board status indicators).

*Is it possible that an advanced board like this doesn't have a single general purpose LED on it?*

Comment: Sure, it’s possible. I don’t know if I’m looking at the right schematics but it looks like there’s an LED on the Arduino connector, D13. You’ll need to read and grok the board docs and look through their example apps.

Comment: This question is about how to read a schematic/documentation and is not withing scope for SO.  Better placed on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Clifford I am often confused where to put questions, since embedded systems are part of both: electronics and software worlds. Also, I was looking at header files, to find "LD1" or "GPIO" definitions, that's why I asked it here. Beginner problems...

But I agree, documentation questions should go to electronics stackexchange. Next time, I'll know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the schematic in that document, it looks like you should be able to use LED LD1 on PI1 (GPIO port I pin 1).

Download the STM32CubeF7 software package.  It should include a blinky program example specifically for your board.  Then see which LED/pin they use in the example program.

Comment: Yes, see the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/f0/14/c1/b9/95/6d/40/4d/DM00190424.pdf/files/DM00190424.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00190424.pdf), page 34/51.

Comment: Aaah now I see it! It's so confusing, this Arduino thing being on my ARM board as I am trying to move away from Arduino :'D
Thanks for help!

Comment: @Jurc192  Note some of the ST eval boards the users manual calls out the ports for the leds in the text (as well as schematic).  This one didnt seem to so you have to defer to the schematic.